# Postgres Function: how to return the first full set of data that occurs after specified date/time

Tags: postgresql, function, set

I have a requirement to extract rows of data, but only if all said rows make a full set. We have a sequence table that is updated every minute, with data for 80 bins. We need to know the status of bins 1 thru 80 every minute as part of our production process.

I am generating a new report (postgres function) that needs to take a snapshot at roughly 00:01:00:AM (IE 1 minute past midnight). Initially I thougtht this to be an easy task, just grab the first 80 rows of data that occur at/after this time, however I see that, depending on network activity and industrial computer priorities, the table is not religiously updated at exactly 00:01:00AM or any minute for that matter. Updates can occur milliseconds or even seconds later, and take 500ms to 800ms to update the database. Sometimes a given minute can be missing altogether (production processes take precedence over data capture, but the sequence data is not super critical anyway)

My thinking is it would be more reliable to look for the first complete set of data anytime from 00:01:00AM onwards. So effectively, I have a table that looks a bit like this:
[image]

Apologies, I know you prefer for images of this manner to not be pasted in this manner, but I could not figure out how to create a textual table like this here (carriage return or Enter button is ignored!)

Basically, the above table is typical, but 1st minute is not guaranteed, and for that matter, I would not be 100% confident that all 80 bins are logged for a given minute. Hence my question: how to return the first complete set of data, where all 80 bins (rows) have been captured for a particular minute?

Thinking about it, I could do some sort of rowcount in the function, ensuring there are 80 rows for a given minute, but this seems less intuitive. I would like to know for sure that for each row of a given minute, bin 1 is represented, bint 2, bin 3...

Ultimately a call to this function will supply a min/max date/time and that period of time will be checked for the first available minute with a full set of bins data.
I am reasonably sure this will involve a window function, as all rows have to be assessed prior to data extraction. I've used windows functions a few times now, but still a green newbie compared to others here, so help is appreciated.

My final code, thanks to help from @klin:-

```
 StartTime = DATE_TRUNC('minute', tme1);
 EndTime = DATE_TRUNC('day', tme1) + '23 hours'::interval;

SELECT "BinSequence".*
FROM "BinSequence"

JOIN(
    SELECT "binMinute" AS binminute, count("binMinute")
    FROM "BinSequence"
    WHERE ("binTime" >= StartTime) AND ("binTime" < EndTime)
    GROUP BY 1
    HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT "binBinNo") = 80 -- verifies that each and every bin is represented in returned data
    ) theseTuplesOnly

ON theseTuplesOnly.binminute = "binMinute"
WHERE ("binTime" >= StartTime) AND ("binTime" < EndTime)

GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
LIMIT 80
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the aggregate function `count(*)` grouping data by minutes (`date_trunc('minute', datestamp)` gives full minutes from `datestamp`), e.g.:

```
create table bins(datestamp time, bin int);
insert into bins values
('00:01:10', 1, 'a'),
('00:01:20', 2, 'b'),
('00:01:30', 3, 'c'),
('00:01:40', 4, 'd'),
('00:02:10', 3, 'e'),
('00:03:10', 2, 'f'),
('00:03:10', 3, 'g'),
('00:03:10', 4, 'h');

select date_trunc('minute', datestamp) as minute, count(bin)
from bins
group by 1
order by 1

  minute  | count 
----------+-------
 00:01:00 |     4
 00:02:00 |     1
 00:03:00 |     3
(3 rows)
```

If you are not sure that all `bins` are unique in consecutive minutes, use `distinct` (this will make the query slower):

```
select date_trunc('minute', datestamp) as minute, count(distinct bin)
...
```

You cannot select counts in aggregated minnutes and all columns of the table in a single simple select. If you want to do that, you should join a derived table or use the operator `in` or use a window function. A join seems to be the simplest:

```
select b.*, count
from bins b
join (
    select date_trunc('minute', datestamp) as minute, count(bin)
    from bins
    group by 1
    having count(bin) = 4
    ) s
on date_trunc('minute', datestamp) = minute
order by 1;

 datestamp | bin | param | count 
-----------+-----+-------+-------
 00:01:10  |   1 | a     |     4
 00:01:20  |   2 | b     |     4
 00:01:30  |   3 | c     |     4
 00:01:40  |   4 | d     |     4
(4 rows)
```

Note also how to use `having()` to filter results in the above query.

You can test the query [here.](http://rextester.com/DHZ77928)

Comment: thanks. this almost works, except I come across that irritating error that insists you either aggregate or put every column in the group by clause. however seeing as everything is forced into the group by clause, the count(distinct bin) remains at 1 and never changes :(

Comment: PS. my actual query  is actually a function and somewhat more complex than the oversimplified version seen in my example above, but the principles are the same.

Comment: PPS. I have a successful row count on a per minute basis working, using a window partition. Unfortunately I just cannot seem to get a distinct count working on a per minute basis, due to the problem mentioned in comment above.